# jquery - find bottom position of tallest column

Tags: jquery

Apologies for what I know should be a simple question! I've got complete brain-freeze and my search results are confusing me even more.

I'm trying to get the bottom edge of three columns, and want to calculate which is the lowest (furthest from the top). Why aren't I getting the correct values - and how do I put them into something that will return the required 'bottom'?

All advice welcome.

```js
function colBottoms( bottom ) {
  bottom = 0;
  $( '.column' ).each( function() {
    var lastP = $( this ).find( 'p' ).last();
    $( lastP ).css( 'color', 'green' );
   var off = $( lastP ).offset();
   var top = off.top;
    $( lastP ).append( top );
   var height = $(  lastP ).height();
    $( lastP ).append( " My 'height' is " + height );
   bottom = top + height;
  console.log( $(  this ).attr( 'id' ) + ' ends at ' + bottom + 'px' );
  });
 }
 colBottoms();
```

```css
#first, #second, #third {
  width: 25%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
#first {
  background: yellow;
}
#first p {
  padding: 15px 10px;
}
#second {
  background: lightblue;
}
#second p {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
#third {
  background: pink;
}
#third p {
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="first" class="column">
  <p>Some content here</p>
  <p>My 'top' is </p>
</div>

<div id="second" class="column">
  <p>Some more content here</p>
  <p>My 'top' is </p>
</div>

<div id="third" class="column">
  <p>My 'top' is </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution where you just create a variable with `0` as a value, then you loop through your `.column`, and you replace the value if the **outerHeight** of the colum + its **top offset** is greater than the variable (that means it will be replaced if a column is longer than the previous ones.

The use of the outerHeight here is because you want the full height including paddings.

```js
var farFromTop = 0
$('.column').each(function() {
var bottomEnds = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight()
console.log($(this).attr('id') + " is at : " + bottomEnds)
  if(bottomEnds > farFromTop){
   farFromTop = bottomEnds
  }
})

console.log("longest column ends at " + farFromTop);
```

```css
#first, #second, #third {
  width: 25%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
#first {
  background: yellow;
}
#first p {
  padding: 15px 10px;
}
#second {
  background: lightblue;
}
#second p {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
#third {
  background: pink;
}
#third p {
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first" class="column">
  <p>Some content here</p>
  <p>My 'top' is </p>
</div>

<div id="second" class="column">
  <p>Some more content here</p>
  <p>My 'top' is </p>
</div>

<div id="third" class="column">
  <p>My 'top' is </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you! I'm [a] overcomplicating things and [b] measuring the wrong height. But ... something's still amiss, surely? It doesn't look like 20px difference between the second & third columns.

Comment: There are 20px on the embedded snippet, expand it and the values will be different (normally 6px :) Hide results then expand snippet then run it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that happens! I copied it into a test file, and Firefox gives different dimensions for the rendered divs. [Screenshot here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ls3o0utn45tbwyi/Screenshot%20%286%29.png?dl=0) Rendered heights are: 168, 108, 102 which are all 8px less than the console logged heights. I have a lot of catching up to do! Thank you for your help, @rafik